# Memory Allocation with 2d Character Array

Tags: c, memory-management, multidimensional-array

So I need to scan in a dictionary of words, max length 19 and dynamically allocate memory to set the size of the dictionary array. I am stuck on how to do this.

```
fscanf(ifp, "%d", &numwords); //Number of words in dictionary

char ** dictionary;


for(i = 0; i < numwords; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 20; j++){
        dictionary[i][j] = (char *) malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
        fscanf(ifp, "%s", &dictionary[i][j]);
        //printf("%s\n", dictionary[i]); //tests that the letter is read in correctly
    }
}
```

I am lost on what is wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is not a 2D array, but a pointer of pointers. Please read the C FAQ on these things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to allocate memory to hold the list of `char*`:

```
dictionary = malloc(sizeof(char*) * numwords);
```

and when you are allocating the `char` array:

```
dictionary[i] = malloc(20); /* No [j] */
```

Note that `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1` so it can be omitted from the `malloc()` argument. When reading the strings, prevent buffer overrun by specifying the maximum width allowed:

```
fscanf(ifp, "%19s", dictionary[i]);
```

There is no requirement for the inner loop. The program needs to read `numwords` from the file, only the outer `for` is required.

Check return values from functions (`malloc()` does not return `NULL` for example and `fscanf()` returns the number of expected assignments).

Comment: I'd rather use `sizeof(*dictionary)`. Also, you forgot to point out that it's not `dictionary[i][j]` that needs to be assigned the result of `malloc()` but only `dictionary[i]`.

Comment: So what you are saying is that before the for loops to read in the dictionary I need to put `dictionary = malloc(sizeof(char*) * numwords);` and that `dictionary[i] = malloc(20);` goes in the for loops?

Comment: Ok so even though it has to be a 2D array it will only need that one loop?

Comment: @Ryan, it isn't really 2d array but a list of pointers, but yes just one loop.

Comment: The reason I ask is because I need to make a binary search now, requiring a 2d array to access specific letters of the words in the dictionary. Sorry to be such a pain on this, just new with memory allocation